# How to replace non-numiric characters from a string MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I need a better way to replace a non-numeric characters in a string.

I have phone numbers like so
(888) 488-6655
888-555-8888
blah blah blah

So I am able to return a clean string by using a simple replace function but I am looking for a better way may be using expression function to replace any non-numeric value. like space slash, backslash, quote..... any none numeric value

this is my current query

```
SELECT
a.account_id,
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.phone_number, '-', ''), ' ', ''), ')', ''),'(','') AS contact_number,
IFNULL(t.ext, '') AS extention,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT number_id FROM contact_numbers WHERE main_number = 1 AND account_id = a.account_id) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS main_number,
'2' AS created_by
FROM cvsnumbers t
INNER JOIN accounts a ON a.company_code = t.company_code
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.phone_number, '-', ''), ' ', ''), ')', ''),'(','')  NOT IN(SELECT contact_number FROM contact_numbers WHERE account_id = a.account_id)
AND LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.phone_number, '-', ''), ' ', ''), ')', ''),'(','') ) = 10
```

How can I change my query to use an REGEX to replace non-numeric values.

Thanks

Comment: As all those other questions containing `mysql` & `regex` indicate, that's not in native `MySQL`. You [could use this](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

Answer (score 1):

This is a brute force approach.

The idea is to create a numbers table, which will index each digit in the phone number.  Keep the digit if it is a number and then group them together.  Here is how it would work:

```
select t.phone_number,
       group_concat(SUBSTRING(t.phone_number, n.n, 1) separator '' order by n
                   ) as NumbersOnly
from cvsnumbers t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
where SUBSTRING(t.phone_number, n.n, 1) between '0' and '9'
group by t.phone_number;
```

This example only looks at the first 3 digits in the number.  You would expand the subquery for `n` to the maximum length of a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the mySql regex flavour but I would give this a go:

```
REPLACE(t.phone_number, '[^\d]+', '')
```

`[^\d]+` means: 'Match everything that is not a digit, once or more times'

You might need to escape the backslash (`[^\\d]+`).

Comment: In MySQL it is not possible to replace in the output using Regex, not without 3rd party code. 
But your Regex is correct :)

Comment: I thought it worked but it is not working. It does not replace all characters from my string